# Efficiently finding the maximum value of a column in a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix

Imagine I have a matrix of the following form:

TestArray = $((a_1,b_1,...),(a_2,b_2,...),(a_3,b_3,...),...)$, where a specific example might be:

TestArray = $((10^6,1,...),(10^7,7,...),(10^3,4,...))$

In the above example, we have $Max[a_i] = 10^7$, and $Max[b_i] = 7$.

In a single line of Mathematica, how can I find the maximum $a_i$, $b_i$, etc.?  Moreover, what is the most computationally efficient manner in which to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 array = RandomInteger[10^5, {20, 5}];

 array // TableForm
```

[image]

```
 Max /@ Transpose@array
 (* {93950, 99694, 94568, 97340, 90524} *)
```

or

```
 #[[Ordering[#, -1]]][[1]] & /@ Transpose[array]
 (* {93950, 99694, 94568, 97340, 90524} *)
```