# Max in every column and Min in every row

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix such as this

```
mat ={{6, 5},{5, 4}}
```

and I want to find the maximum in every column and minimum in every row.  After that I have to get the same number of both.  I write this

```
Max /@ Transpose[mat]
```

and

```
Min /@ mat
```

The results are `{6,5}` and `{5,4}`.  However I am not sure how I can find that 5 is the same for both.  And also it will be good to have all commands to be in one cycle.

Answer (score 1):

```
mat = {{6, 5}, {5, 4}};
```

Those row/column indices `i,j` for which the minimal row element is the same as the maximal column element is:

```
Tuples[{Min /@ mat, Max /@ Transpose[mat]}] //
 Position[ArrayReshape[Differences[#, {0, 1}][[All, 1]], Dimensions[mat]], 0] &
```

> {{1, 2}}

Comment: This code works for row 1 but when I wrote this matt = {{5, 4}, {6, 5}}; the answer is {{1, 4}} but have to be row 2 column 2 .

Comment: @M.Alexis I can't reproduce that. Try wrapping `With[{mat = matt}, ....]` around  the code.

Comment: I also tried the solution from @MeMyselfI and it works fine for both matrices, as well as something along the lines of Table[RandomInteger[{0, 10}], {i, 4}, {j, 4}] (it might take a bigger matrix or some repetitions to get something other than a blank table). For a way that is faster than Position [see here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65708/how-do-i-find-the-position-of-the-maximum-value-in-each-column-of-a-table)